# Fading in input field, displacing the rest of the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, input

I'm making a website, and, the main part of the website is a canvas where I, through javascript and jquery made an application. For getting input from the user, I was advised to fade in some input fields placed using absolute positioning. It works, but as they fade in, they somewhat displace the rest of the website. Anything I can do to make it not displace the rest of the website? Also, be sure to let me know of other ways of getting input from the user.

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/48890691/index.html)'s a link to a hosted version of the website.

Comment: Give a link to where this is happening or create the same scenario in e.g. JSFiddle.

Comment: Can you post some code? Perhaps using jsFiddle. Anyway, an option would be to set your input fields' position as absolute.

Comment: I am using absolute positioning. Anyway, I'm uploading a version of the website so you guys can see the code.

Comment: you're not using absolute positioning...they're relatively positioned

Comment: Centreally aligned as in `align="center"`?

Comment: See, I have set absolute width right, and wrapped them in said wrapper (didn't give it a set width though, is it required?) and I have no idea where the inputs have gone to.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8357/discussion-between-chimoo-and-holythunder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comments are turning into an answer, I may as well add the answer:

Another way of getting user input is [prompt()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_prompt.asp)

To fix your absolute positioning problems, wrap your content in a wrapper div e.g:

```
<div style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;position:relative;">
  <!--content here-->
</div>
```

Then make sure each of your inputs has their position as absolute.

NOTE: The absolute values you use will no longer be relative to the document, but to the new wrapper, so `top: 0; left: 0` will place an element at the top left of the wrapper

Comment: Oh, I thought I should just wrap the inputs. Though, my whole content's width is higher than 500, should I just adjust that?

Comment: @HolyThunder there's a bug in your css `left 500px` should be `left:500px`. Also, if you can't find them, make sure you first set them as visible and `top:0;left:0` then adjust to suit

Comment: Oh, I fixed it... having some problems due to some other things, so it couldn't see them >.<. It seems they're ok. Just asking also, is prompt() like an alert but with an input box? like, would it open another "window"?

Comment: Yes its similar to alert(), it's not the nicest of things, but as I said it's the easiest way to get user input using javascript

Comment: Ah, I won't be using that than. Also, I got it working now, just need to adjust some stuff, but thanks :D. Also, will it, even using absolute positioning, not get screwed up in other screen resolutions?

Comment: Not if you keep it in that relatively positioned wrapper, no. Be aware though that if your wrapper is wider than about 1000px, some users may not see the whole thing without scrolling